# spark list selected item coordinates

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have a list with custom item renderers.  What I would like is when one of the list items is selected to position another control OUTSIDE the list to the same vertical position as the selected item.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

USe the [itemClick](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#event%3aitemClick) event to get a reference to the itemRenderer that was clicked; and from there you can get the X and Y properties.

In a Spark List, you can probably do something using the [click](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3aclick) event, although the itemRenderer is note explicitly exposed; but I think the target property may give you a hook to the itemRenderer.

If all else fails, you could have your custom itemRenderer dispatch it's own event which includes the global X and Y positions.

Comment: That is until the renderer instance gets recycled... You would need to track the instance of the renderer through the data item by assigning something like data.render = this, and track any changes to list.selectedItem.renderer. This way you always have an up to date reference to the current renderer instance if it changes (which it has a habit of doing unexpectadly).

Comment: @drkstr I understood from the original post that @FuzzyBear wanted a reference to the itemRenderer when it is selected.  It is unlikely the renderer will recycle between being selected and the event handler being fired.  However, if you needs to coordinate layouts, then yes he'll have to do something on list scrolling to move his "other items".

Comment: @Flextras Yeah good point. Most likely the use case would not involve virtual layout or scrolling, which would trigger the recycling process. I was thinking more about something that had to remain aligned to the selected item as it moves in a scrollable list. Even still, I would be wary when breaking the golden rule of item renderers: "Though shall not rely on the instance of an item renderer". But you are right, there shouldn't be any problem if the control doesn't need to be "bound" to the location of the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

This thread has some code samples that demonstrate how to do something like this:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/2539545#2539545